# pip3 assumes its using regular pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

```
❯ pip3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3241, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3225, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 585, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 598, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.2.3' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

For some reason it says it's accessing `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7`.

If I type in `which pip3` it outputs, `/usr/local/bin/pip3`.
And so I used that to put in my path like so, `export PATH="/usr/local/bin/pip3:$PATH"`

I also did the same thing with python3:
`which python3` and outputs, `/usr/bin/python3`
And then I used it to put in my path:
`export PATH="/usr/bin/python3:$PATH"`

However, for some reason my MacBook thinks to use python 2 and regular pip.
I want to be able to use pip3.

Comment: What do you get if you enter `which python3`?

Comment: @pepoluan When I type `which python3` my output is  `/usr/bin/python3`